# Телеграм бот C# telegram bot is not responding. Please try again later

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, telegram

Помогите разобраться. 
Пишу бота использую inline keyboard. Kогда нажимаю на кнопку спустя секунд 10 вылетает сообщение  "is not responding. Please try again later" при этом всем функционал работает весь. И на кнопке индикатор всегда крутится. 
Использую Telegram.Bot API.

Код inline keyboard:

```
      private InlineKeyboardButton[][] GetInlineKeyboard(string[] stringArray)
    {

        var keyboardInline = new InlineKeyboardButton[stringArray.Length][];

        for (var i = 0; i < stringArray.Length; i++)
        {
            var keyboardButtons = new InlineKeyboardButton[1];
            keyboardButtons[0] = new InlineKeyboardButton
            {
                Text = stringArray[i],
                CallbackData = stringArray[i],
            };

            keyboardInline[i] = keyboardButtons;
        }

        return keyboardInline;
    }
```

Код вызова:

```
   _keyboardMarkup = new InlineKeyboardMarkup(GetInlineKeyboard(GetSomeStringArr()));
                await _client.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id, message.Text, ParseMode.Default, false,
                    false, 0,
                    _keyboardMarkup);
```

[image: screen]

Comment: А что должно произойти?

Comment: @playerone что бы сообщение не вылетало, и индикатор перестал крутиться..

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы перестало крутиться, 
нужно отослать через метод `AnswerCallbackQueryAsync`, даже если нет сообщения.

[читать тут](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery)